# How to coressponds RGB values to its colour name?

Tags: java

Is there any possible method in java that allows the programmer to retrieve color name from RGB values. Ex : R:255, G:255, B: 0 as yellow.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not; only the other way round. There are static fields in the Color class for the typical colors.

Intellij IDEA has a nice feature, in the sense that when you define a color the actual color appears in the left (near the line number) on the line the color was defined. Clicking there you can choose the color, and the amount of R, G and B is automatically set depending on the color selected.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is find someone who has implemented (essentially) a map of this.  I don't know that anyone has done so, but there is nothing to keep you from doing it yourself.  There is no way to determine the color name strictly programmatically.

You could do something like:

```
Map<Color, String> colors = new HashMap<Color, String>();

public void populateColors() {
    colors.put(new Color(255, 000, 000), "Red");
    colors.put(new Color(000, 255, 000), "Green");
    colors.put(new Color(000, 000, 255), "Blue");
    colors.put(new Color(255, 255, 000), "Yellow");
    ...
}

public String getColorName(Color color) {
    if (!colors.containsKey(color)) {
        return "Unknown";
    }

    return colors.get(color);
}
```

But also note the limitations of this; if you're allowing users to select the colors (especially if you're using an imprecise tool like a colorpicker instead of manual text entry), if they happen to select `255, 254, 0` instead of `255, 255, 0`, then they will get an unknown color (not yellow, despite the fact that they will look the same to the human eye).  There are 256^3 = 16,777,216 colors.  There is no way they all have a name.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not likely that a feasible implementation of such a thing can be provided , considering that there are still a myriad unnamed colors.

You can use some of the well known colors

Color.BLACK, Color.CYAN etc

[Refer docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)